# List all RTMP streams available

Tags: rtmp, flash-media-server

I'm streaming live video from Flash Media Server via RTMP. Is there any way to get a list of all available streams?

I already know the names of a few streams, but I'm wondering if there might be others, is there a way to find them?

Comment: did you find anyway? I have the same problem

Comment: Sorry @ananda, the best way I found was to guess their names.